# null values sent to controller after jQuery Post

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I have a bit of code where I'm trying to send a Viewmodel back to the controller using Ajax post.  If I write the code one way, it passes correctly, and another way it returns null or 0 values within the viewmodel.

The way that works:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        $(".boxItem").change(function (event) {
            var url = "/Search/GetBoxChangeInfo";
            $.post(url, @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model)), function (data) {
                $("#column-1").html(data);
            });
        });
    });
```

And the way that returns null values:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        $(".boxItem").change(function (event) {
            var url = "/Search/GetBoxChangeInfo";
            $.post(url, { json: @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model)) }, function (data) {
                $("#column-1").html(data);
            });
        });
    });
```

i need to use it the second way because I need to also pass parameters back about the selected value and ID, so it will look something like:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        $(".boxItem").change(function (event) {
            var str = $(this).attr('id');
            var num = $(this).val();
            var url = "/Search/GetBoxChangeInfo";
            $.post(url, { json: @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model)), id : str, selected : num  }, function (data) {
                $("#column-1").html(data);
            });
        });
});
```

My controller looks like this btw:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult GetBoxChangeInfo(EventViewModel json)
{ 
     //stuff
}
```

EDIT - as requested, here is EventViewModel structure

```
[JsonObject(MemberSerialization.OptIn)]
public class EventViewModel
{
    public int EventNumber { get; set; }
    public List<EventItemsViewModel> EventItems { get; set; }
    public List<LocationViewModel> Locations { get; set; }
    public int StartLocationID { get; set; }
    public bool Outbound { get; set; }
    public List<int> SelectedEvents { get; set; }
    public List<DurationsViewModel> Durations { get; set; }
}
```

Anyone know why this might be happening?  Is there a limit to home much can be sent to the controller this way - it is quite a complex viewmodel, so wondered if that could be someting to do with it.

Thanks

Comment: Could you post the structure of your `EventViewModel`?

Comment: Hi Matty - edited original post to add structure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.boxItem').change(function (event) {
        var str = $(this).attr('id');
        var num = $(this).val();
        var url = '@Url.Action("GetBoxChangeInfo", "Search")';
        $.ajax({
            url: url,
            contentType: 'application/json',
            data: JSON.stringify({ 
                json: @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model)), 
                id: str, 
                selected: num  
            }),
            success: function(data) {
                $("#column-1").html(data);
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Things to notice:

- `contentType: 'application/json'`
- `JSON.stringify` to convert the object into a JSON string
- `var url = '@Url.Action("GetBoxChangeInfo", "Search")';` to avoid hardcoding urls

Comment: Funnily enough, I started with this, but it doesn't go into the controller action at all, which was why I switched to jQuery post.  If I stick an alert in just above the ajax call, it fires that, but nothing else. Any thoughts where I could be going wrong?

Comment: Did you inspect the AJAX request with FireBug? Look at the response sent by the server to understand why it doesn't reach the controller.

Comment: Good thinking - managed to fix that and it now works.  Bringing back null values still but I think it's for different reasons now, if that makes sense.  Will keep looking and report back...

Comment: Ok, I had a few issues to sort out, but this was pretty much it. Thanks for your help Darin

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a limit to home much can be sent to the controller this way - it is quite a complex viewmodel, so wondered if that could be someting to do with it.

Yes there is and it's 1000 HTTP Collection keys and you can configure that yourself in the web.config. Try setting the value to 4000 first, then you can lower it a bit if you like. Try this:

```
<appSettings>
    <add key="aspnet:MaxHttpCollectionKeys" value="4000" />
</appSettings>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this
http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/

$.ajax({
  type: 'POST',
  url: url,
  data: data,
  success: success,
  dataType: dataType
});

, I mean not shorthand Axaj Call. You have options like "success", "error", "completed" and can isolate issue.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same *error* on ASP.NET MVC. On your model, you put `ConvertEmptyStringToNull = false` on your model's property's attribute:

```
[DisplayFormat(ConvertEmptyStringToNull = false)]
```

E.g.

```
public class Person
{
    [DisplayFormat(ConvertEmptyStringToNull = false)]
    public string Lastname { get; set; }
    [DisplayFormat(ConvertEmptyStringToNull = false)]
    public string Firstname { get; set; }
    [DisplayFormat(ConvertEmptyStringToNull = false)]
    public string Middlename { get; set; }
}
```

I documented when I encountered the same thing at this post: http://www.ienablemuch.com/2011/08/empty-string-is-empty-string.html